# How to create virtual networks by using libvirt?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, qemu

I have installed qemu/kvm and have tried to create some virtual machines and network them together.

What I would like to achieve is 2-3 virtual machines in their own private network (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24), all machines should be able to access external network, but only 1 machine should get IP that is accessible from outside.

```
External Network
  .                     +-----------------+
  |                     | VM 1            |
  |                  +--| IP: 10.0.0.11   |
+-----------------+  |  | IP: 82.130.y.y  |
| Host            |--|  +-----------------+
| IP: 82.130.x.x  |  |
+-----------------+  |  +-----------------+
                     |--| VM 2            |
                     |  | IP: 10.0.0.12   |
                     |  +-----------------+
                     |
                     |  +-----------------+
                     +--| VM 3            |
                        | IP: 10.0.0.13   |
                        +-----------------+
```

I've tried to to add `br0`-bridge with `brctl` and bridged it with `eth0`, but that set also my host's nameserver to 192.168.1.1 and made it inacessible.

How should I do the configuration?

**My current setup:**

*Name servers:*

```
# /etc/resolv.conf 
domain kyla.fi
search kyla.fi
nameserver 82.130.0.1
nameserver 82.130.63.1
```

*Interfaces and IP addresses:*

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:71:c4:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 82.130.x.x/26 brd 82.130.x.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

edit:
*Added configuration for `br0`:*

```
# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

just `virbr0` missing

Answer (score 1):

You need *two* networks, not just one. The VM connected to both networks must then have two virtual NICs, each of which is connected to one of the networks.

```
External Network
  .                     +-----------------+
  |                br0  | VM 1            |
  |                  +--| IP: 82.130.y.y  |
+-----------------+  |  |   IP: 10.0.0.11 |--+
| Host            |--+  +-----------------+  |
| IP: 82.130.x.x  |                          |
+-----------------+     +-----------------+  |
                        | VM 2            |  |
                        | IP: 10.0.0.12   |--+  virbr1
                        +-----------------+  |
                                             |
                        +-----------------+  |
                        | VM 3            |  |
                        | IP: 10.0.0.13   |--+
                        +-----------------+
```

Create a *new* virtual network in virsh or virt-manager as an isolated network with the private IP range you wish.

Comment: How should I create br0? Steps I've tried `brctl addbr br0` and `brctl addif br0 eth0`, and as soon as I've added the interface Host becomes inaccessible :/

Comment: `br0` is working now, but I'm still missing `virbr0`

Answer (score 1):

There is not need to have two NICs for VM 1.
I recommend to configure 10.0.0.0/24 as a "routed network", then configure your router to route 10.0.0.0/24 via 82.130.x.x (the host's IP) and configure firewall rules in the host to allow incoming packets with destination 10.0.0.11 and then to block remaining incoming packets with destination 10.0.0.0/24.

If you want to keep two NICs, you still have to configure the router to route 82.130.y.y via 82.130.x.x, and 10.0.0.0/24 must be configured as a "natted network".

Check the wiki:

- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking
- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#Routed_mode_2
- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#NAT_mode
- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking